# Semantic ui tab update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, history, semantic-ui

The tab system works fine but I want the tab to update every time I click to open it. I mean, if I edit the div it will update the message.

Without refreshing the whole page!

Anyone know how?

I tried with this:

```js
$('#menu .item')
  .tab({
    history: true,
    cache: false,
    apiSettings: {
      loadingDuration: 300,
      mockResponse: function(settings) {
        var response = {
          first: 'AJAX Tab One',
          second: 'AJAX Tab Two',
          third: 'AJAX Tab Three'
        };
        return response[settings.urlData.tab];
      }
    },
    auto: true
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

http://semantic-ui.com

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is a little late, but I think you're looking for the `alwaysRefresh` tab setting mentioned [here](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html#/settings). The default value is false, but setting it to true should reload the tab's content every time:

```
$('#menu .item')
  .tab({
    alwaysRefresh: true,
    history: true,
    cache: false,
    apiSettings: {
      loadingDuration: 300,
      mockResponse: function(settings) {
        var response = {
          first: 'AJAX Tab One',
          second: 'AJAX Tab Two',
          third: 'AJAX Tab Three'
        };
        return response[settings.urlData.tab];
      }
    },
  auto: true
});
```